# Java Spring 4 (Annotated) Rest Controller not being hit by REST Client tool in Firefox

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

> Hi,
>
> I have a problem that is very confusing for me because the mapping should work and it looks like it does map when the Spring Boot is started in debug mode. I don't know where else I can check for an obvious solution to this problem.
>
> Here is the application.properties:

```
server.port=8082
server.contextPath = /
```

> Here is the SpringBootInitializer class that adds a further "/api" to the >Servlet registration:

```
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Bean
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    return new DispatcherServlet();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
    final ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet(), "/api/*");

    final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("contextClass", "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
    params.put("contextConfigLocation", "org.spring.sec2.spring");
    params.put("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");
    registration.setInitParameters(params);

    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return registration;
}

//

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.initializers(new MyApplicationContextInitializer()).sources(App.class);
}

public static void main(final String... args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class).initializers(new MyApplicationContextInitializer()).run(args);
}
}
```

> Here is the Controler which adds a further "users" to the mapping. The method >which I have set a debug point is the findAll and requires no futher mapping to >get to it (i.e. the root of /users/:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = users)
public class UserController extends AbstractController<User> {

@Autowired
private IUserService userService;

public UserController() {
    super(User.class);
}

// API

// find

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void getItsWorking() {
    System.out.println("It's Working!!!");
}

}
```

> Here is the User entity:

```
@Entity
public class User implements IEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="user_id")
private Long user_id;

@Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String password;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Boolean locked;


public User() {
    super();
}

public User(final String nameToSet, final String passwordToSet, /*final       
Set<Role> rolesToSet,*/ final Boolean lockedToSet) {
    super();

    name = nameToSet;
    password = passwordToSet;
    locked = lockedToSet;
}

// API

public Long getId() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setId(final Long idToSet) {
    user_id = idToSet;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(final String nameToSet) {
    name = nameToSet;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(final String emailToSet) {
    email = emailToSet;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(final String passwordToSet) {
    password = passwordToSet;
}

public Boolean getLocked() {
    return locked;
}

public void setLocked(final Boolean lockedToSet) {
    locked = lockedToSet;
}

}
```

> Here is the output on my Spring Boot debug when it starts up:

```
Mapped "{[/users],methods=[GET]}" onto public    
java.util.List<org.um.persistence.model.User> 
     org.um.web.controller.UserController.findAll(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```

> So, it looks like it is mapping correctly, but when I hit it using the Rest >Client tool add on in Firefox, I get the following when doing a "GET" on the >following url: http://localhost:8082/api/users using Content-Type: application/json in my header .

[image: Rest Client 404 Image]

> ***What is going on?*** ***Very confused.***

Comment: Try changing `@RequestMapping(value = users)` to `@RequestMapping(value = "/api/users")`.

Answer (score 1):

You should put a `@RequestMapping("/api")` on you class, and a `@RequestMapping("/users")` on your method (that should preferably return something to the client).

This ways your endpoint will be exposed as `/api/users` and you will be able to easily add further endpoints under `/api/*` into this class.

Comment: thank you for your response Simon, but still the same 404. What else should I check?

Comment: It turned out that I had a SecurityFilterChain class from a previous target build that prevented me access to the controller. Once cleared and rebuilt, it hit the rest controller method with no problem.